# How to animate background delay in before and not immediately?

Tags: html, css

I try to animate background of the div. not it's not works.

The red is appear immediately. the background property of `before` not do the delay.

How to fix it so first it will be no background and after 5s the color will show in 5s duration?

```css
div {
  position:relative;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
 }
 
 div:before {
    content: '';
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:red;
    transition:all 5s ease;
    transition-delay: 5s;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  animation: test 5s;
}

@keyframes test {
  0% {
    background-color: white;
  }

  100% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```